# About AngularDart, How to solve angular_router: ^2.0.0-alpha incompatibility with angular 5.0.0-alpha?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-router

Today I started trying advice from @matanlurey in git#676 (https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/issues/676). In my project pubspec.yaml file:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.24.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  angular: ^5.0.0-alpha
  angular_components: ^0.9.0-alpha
  angular_forms: ^1.0.1-alpha
  angular_router: ^2.0.0-alpha
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1
  sass_builder: ^1.0.0
```

but Resolving dependencies...

```
Incompatible version constraints on angular:
- angular_components 0.9.0-alpha depends on version 5.0.0-alpha
- angular_forms 1.0.1-alpha depends on version ^5.0.0-alpha
- angular_router 2.0.0-alpha depends on version ^4.0.0
- huastecappadmin depends on version ^5.0.0-alpha
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add

```
dependency_overrides:
  angular: ^5.0.0-alpha
```

but it might not work.
In this case you'd need to wait until an update for `angular_router` that is compatible with Angular 5 is released.

See also https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/issues/676